# this is undefined in React method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, synthesizer

I am trying to make a simple synthesizer with React and the Web Audio API and having trouble with some methods. Here is my code:

```
import * as React from "react"

class Synth extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 0.5};
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.setup = this.setup.bind(this);
        this.createKey = this.createKey.bind(this);
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        this.audioContext = null;
        this.oscList = [];
        this.mainGainNode = null;
        this.wavePicker = document.querySelector("select[name='waveform']");
        this.volumeControl = document.querySelector("input[name='volume']");

        this.noteFreq = null;
        this.customWaveform = null;
        this.sineTerms = null;
        this.cosineTerms = null;
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setup();
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        });
    }

    createNoteTable(){
        let noteFreq = [];
        for (let i=0; i< 9; i++) {
            noteFreq[i] = [];
        }

        noteFreq[3]["C"] = 130.81;
        noteFreq[3]["C#"] = 138.59;
        noteFreq[3]["D"] = 146.83;
        noteFreq[3]["D#"] = 155.56;
        noteFreq[3]["E"] = 164.81;
        noteFreq[3]["F"] = 174.61;
        noteFreq[3]["F#"] = 185.00;
        noteFreq[3]["G"] = 196.00;
        noteFreq[3]["G#"] = 207.65;
        //etc...
        return noteFreq;
    }
    createKey(note, octave, freq){
        console.log("createKey() is firing");
        let keyElement = document.createElement("li");

        switch (freq) {
            case 130.81:
                keyElement.className = "white c1"
                break;
            case 146.83:
                keyElement.className = "black cs1"
                break;
            case 164.81:
                keyElement.className = "white c1"
                break;
            case 174.61:
                keyElement.className = "white d1"
                break;
            //etc...
        
            default:
                break;
        }
        keyElement.dataset["freq"] = freq;
        keyElement.dataset["note"] = note;
        keyElement.dataset["octave"] = octave;
        keyElement.addEventListener("mousedown", this.notePressed, false);
        keyElement.addEventListener("mouseup", this.noteReleased, false);
        keyElement.addEventListener("mouseover", this.notePressed, false);
        keyElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", this.noteReleased, false);

        return keyElement;
    }
    
    setup(){
        
        this.audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

        this.noteFreq = this.createNoteTable();

        
        this.mainGainNode = this.audioContext.createGain();
        this.mainGainNode.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
        this.mainGainNode.gain.value = this.state.value;
        
        this.noteFreq.forEach(function(keys, idx) {
            let keyList = Object.entries(keys);
            let octaveElem = document.createElement("div");
            keyList.forEach(function(key){

                console.log("key[0] = " + key[0]);
                console.log("idx = " + idx);
                console.log("key[1] = " + key[1]);
                try {
                    octaveElem.appendChild(this.createKey(key[0], idx, key[1]));
                } catch(error){
                    console.log("Cannot create key... " + error);
                }
            });
        });
    
        this.sineTerms = new Float32Array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1]);
        this.cosineTerms = new Float32Array(this.sineTerms.length);
        this.customWaveform = this.audioContext.createPeriodicWave(this.cosineTerms, this.sineTerms);
    
        for (let i=0; i<9; i++) {
            this.oscList[i] = {};
        }
    }
```

then I have the notePressed() and noteReleased() functions but these seem to work fine.

The problem is when this.createKey() is called I get this error :
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createKey')

As you can see, I tried binding pretty much every method I have to see if it would help but it didn't. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function that needs to be bound to the correct context is one that's calling `createKey`. In this case, that function is anonymous - `this.noteFreq.forEach(function(keys, idx)`. You have a few options, but just make it an arrow function and be done with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your error is probably due to the `function` keyword in your `forEach` loops. There you lose your `this` scope. You can fix it by using `for of` or an arrow function.

```
this.noteFreq.forEach((keys, idx) => {
    ...
    keyList.forEach((key) => { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, your code looks more like a normal ES6 class, and not a React class. In React, you don't use `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild`. Instead, you should use the `render()` function to render the document.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I do use render as well but I was having trouble and tried ES6 until I could fix the problem. I can now reformat it in the render() function.